# AWS CloudFormation conditions

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have two conditions in my CloudFormation template which are used to choose which resource to deploy based on environment. However when referencing the resource later in the template CloudFormation throws "Unresolved resource dependencies" error. Any idea whats wrong?

Template is shortened for readability. It is working fine without conditions.

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String

Conditions:
  IsProduction: !Equals [!Ref EnvironmentName, production]
  IsNotProduction: !Not [!Equals [!Ref EnvironmentName, production]]

Resources:
  Lambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Condition: IsNotProduction

  Lambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Condition: IsProduction

  LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub /aws/lambda/${Lambda}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since the template is shortened, it's not that easy to tell what causes this error.

One thing that is problematic though, is that both of your Lambdas are called `"Lambda"`. That won't work, you need to call them differently in your resources section.

Comment: The reference to lambda in log group is the only one in the template which i assume is causing the error. I also assumed that i can have 2 resources with the same logical id because it will only create one of them but i quess i cant. Nice catch.

Comment: In my experience, I have found that is often easier to use an `!If` statement for the properties that are actually different so you can use a single logical ID. It keeps other parts of the template cleaner, such as references that are the same and which do not depend on the condition.

Comment: My goal was to disable gradual deployments for staging and enable them for production but AutoPublishAlias attribute does not work with conditions.